# Varnish 4, cache page with cookies

Tags: php, cookies, varnish, varnish-vcl

I want to cache every page (even with cookies), backend in php is not prepared for this, so it's sending multiple Set-Cookie headers. When I remove all session_start and setcookie funcitons, the page HITs, but when I set my vcl to varnish do it automatically for me, page allways MISSes.

Here is my **default.vcl**:

```
vcl 4.0;

backend default {
    .host = "myhost.app";
    .port = "80";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    unset req.http.cookie;
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (obj.hits > 0) {
       set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
    } else {
       set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
    }
}
```

Comment: What response header values for Cache-Control and TTL are the php files returning?

Comment: Hi @MarcelDumont, I think it is irrelevant, I don't want to change my backend. Is it possible to unset and then set CacheControl and TTL by varnish VCL, so varnish wourld cache all the pages?

Comment: Reason for asking is that there are more factors then only the cookies which can cause an unexpected pass in varnish. and CacheControl and TTL are often the cause. So it's relevant. it would be ideal if you can show the full request and response header.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are going into muddy waters, but try forcing a ttl:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
   set beresp.ttl = 120 s;
   unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
}
```

Check that you are not breaking things by caching ignoring cookies and ttls.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing cache MISS every time and updated `sub vcl_backend_response{..}` as mentioned by Jorge Nerín. Now It was showing cache HIT, but login was not happening. It was obvious because of `unset beresp.http.set-cookie;`. So I get idea from [Manipulating request headers in VCL](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/users-guide/vcl-example-manipulating-headers.html) to unset cookie based on URL. I applied same in`vcl_backend_response`. In my app login URL contains `auth`. So I updated to `unset beresp.http.set-cookie;` every where except when URL contain `auth`. Now login is happening and also cache HIT. Hope this helps community

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
 set beresp.ttl = 120 s;
 if ((bereq.url ~ "auth")){
  }
 else{
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
 }
 #rest of code
}
```